# Why are isolated systems even useful?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

Consider we wanted to analyze how long will it take for the coffee kept in a cup on a table, to cool down to room temperature. For this analysis, we can consider coffee as our system. Neglecting any matter that leaves as vapor, we can model coffee as a closed system.

Now let us say, this coffee was kept in a well-insulated flask. If we now consider coffee as the system, it will be an isolated system. However, what kind of analysis will motivate me to choose coffee (which is an isolated system here) as the system?

In the first case, we had a motive - analyzing how long it takes for coffee to cool down. What motive do I have in choosing an isolated system?

I mean, isolated systems do not interact with their surroundings, then why are they even useful? In open and closed systems we have energy transfer which brings changes in the system, we can analyze those changes. But what do we analyze in isolated systems?

Comment: Wdym by what will you study?

Comment: As per my understanding, before choosing a system we need to be clear about what we are trying to study or analyse. I mean what is the problem statement. In the first case, it is clear that we want to analyse how coffee cools over time and for doing that study/analysis we take coffee as the system which is a closed system. In the second case, what will be my motivation to choose coffee (which would make an isolated system) as the system? When we choose isolated systems, what are we trying to analyse?

Comment: While an isolated system by definition does not interact in any way with its environment, there are potentially internal interactions that we can study if the system is not initially in internal equilibrium.

Comment: @BobD Oh. That's interesting. In this case of coffee kept in an insulated flask, can I apply the same logic? that is will the coffee initially not be in internal equilibrium and over time will achieve?

Comment: Let's say your cup of coffee is  initially not in an insulated flask and has no cover. Clearly the system is not in equilibrium with the surroundings as heat and mass transfer (evaporation) are occurring. You then surround surround it with rigid solid insulation. At that point you have an isolated system that is not initially in internal equilibrium (there are internal temperature gradients).  Eventually the liquid and gas phases of the system will come to thermal equilibrium.

Comment: @BobD Ohh got it. I'm grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way that an isolated system is relevantly analyzed is in the case of removing a barrier between two parts of a system, each part of which is initially at thermodynamic equilibrium by itself.  The combined 2-part system is contained in a rigid adiabatic enclosure.  The barrier may be a piston that is suddenly released, or a wall that is suddenly removed.

An example is a cylinder containing water at two different temperatures.  When the adiabatic barrier is removed, the two volumes of water equilibrate thermally.  Another example is a piston between gases at two different pressures initially.  When the piston is released, the two volumes equilibrate with respect to pressure.

Answer (score 1):

An isolated system is a simplification.  It makes things easier to quantify.  It is also a system that we can all agree upon.  If I "isolate" a system and you "isolate" a system in a different way, we can generally expect the results to agree, or one of us needs to improve our isolation.

An isolated system should be chosen to be as small as it can be, but no smaller.  The smaller you make it, the simpler the math will be, but if you make it too small, the assumptions of isolation start to break down.

An insulated thermos of coffee is a decent isolated system, but it's simple.  It's already quiescent, having reached its steady state temperature.  A more interesting system might be that cup of coffee with an ice cube thrown in.  If we built the system around either the coffee or the ice cube, we'd find there's heat transfer -- worse, its not even simple heat transfer that can be modeled as a sink at a fixed temperature.  So isolating those systems becomes a poor choice.  When we include both the ice cube and the coffee, we get a closed system that behaves in an interesting way.

I always try to remember "neccesary and sufficient" conditions.  When picking a system to model, I'll go back and forth asking "what is neccesary to model this correctly" and "what is sufficient."  Often there's one answer that I iteratively approach, so I'll go with that system.